# How can I find the most used or average rgb color from all pixels inside a defined section of a web browser's viewport?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, colors, material-design

### My Ridiculous Idea:

I know this is ambitious. Please be ambitious with me...

I have a design scheme in mind, for a web app, based on Google's Material Design standards and iOS's frosted glass/gaussian blur effect. I would like **to have the top-most-layer "material" (section) be one solid color which reflects the colors of any other page content layered below** it, whether that be, by finding the average rgb color of all content within a defined region of the viewport, or the most used rgb colors within that region of the viewport.

**For Example:**
[Mockup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEw5X.png)

### Help from the Inter-webs...

I have found the following resources, plugins, & tutorials which achieve similar ideas:

- https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/

I can add more links in the comments, if people are interested. It's just that the forum limits how many I can post at once.

### Why none of those resources help me...

So, the main issue is that most projects and plugins like this on the web, are geared towards overlaying a blur, on a static image. **I need the top-most material (section) to update color dynamically as content below changes**, as well as needing it to take images and other elements into consideration, alike.

Please, please, please help me? **I understand that this is ridiculous and probably barely supported by any browser, as well as extremely slow to load for a web page**, but if there's a way, I'd love to know about it.

**Thanks so much folks!**

Comment: I'd propose a slight change. The average color of other areas is probably going to leave you with a lot of brown. I would probably focus on finding the nearest material color to the majority color. It probably wouldn't be too bad if you were inspecting the DOM within the viewport but processing the images is going to be tricky and slow. The moment the user scrolls you have to throw away whatever processing you've done and start over.

Comment: Sounds like you need a graphic designer, not a program. This is still a task better-left to the human eye, in my opinion.

Comment: If you could preprocess the images to find the average color and set that in the DOM I think your project is doable.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I agree about the majority color idea. And I suppose I could pre-process images to find the most used color. That way I could pre-define the color of each element on the page.

Comment: Then, if I could find a way to only trigger a reload of the color, when an element has either entered or exited the region of the viewport where the dynamically colored element is, I could significantly reduce the frequency of reloading.

Comment: @Kevin_Earley If this is a website where you have control of the backend/server I would scan the image when it is uploaded and assign a color value to it in your database.  You could then use that value when generating your html pages.  This would also make it fast and you wont have to worry about browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code is something like this.

1. Loop through all the elements (or maybe just the divs) within the current
   viewport.
2. Find the height, width, color
3. Calculate the total size of each color
4. Determine the majority color
5. Find the nearest material color